# Array inside object undefined after subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, subscribe

i'm trying to get an element after multiples http requests but there is an asynch problem that i can't resolve. Post my code:

Get function in my service:

```
get() {
return new Observable(project => {
  this.channelsService.get().subscribe(
    stations => {
      this._stations = stations;
      this._stations.forEach((station) => {
        station.cssClass = this.channelsService.getCss(station.id.split('/').pop());
        station.plstation$thumbnails = this.channelsService.getThumbnails(station.id.split('/').pop());
        if (station.plstation$callSign !== '') {
          const watchliveUrl = this.watchLiveApi + station.plstation$callSign + '/?schema=1.0.0';
          this.http.get(watchliveUrl).subscribe(data => {
            const body = data.json();
            station.currentListing = body.currentListing;
            station.nextListing = body.nextListing;
            project.next(stations);
            project.complete()
          });
        }
      });

    }, (error) => {
      this.mapErrorService.mapError(error, 'Listing service (1)');
    });
});
```

}

get() used and subscribe:

```
 constructor(private listingService: ListingService) {
this.listingService.get().subscribe((stations) => {
  this.stripDetails.channelList = stations;
  // stations[6].currentListing Not undefined
  console.log(stations);
  // Now is undefined
  console.log(stations[6].currentListing);

});  }
```

How can i define stations[6].currentListing?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the `Observable` from `http.get()` into a `Promise`, but you never do anything with that `Promise`. So although `stations` is defined where you say, the `Promise` will not have completed so the `currentListing` attribute will be undefined.

When using an Observable or a Promise you must always wait for the result. So in this case if you want to use promises you need to gather them all together and not output `project` until they have all completed.

Something like:

```
get() {
return new Observable(project => {
  this.channelsService.get().subscribe(
    stations => {
      this._stations = stations;
      let responses = this._stations.map((station) => {
        station.cssClass = this.channelsService.getCss(station.id.split('/').pop());
        station.plstation$thumbnails = this.channelsService.getThumbnails(station.id.split('/').pop());
        if (station.plstation$callSign !== '') {
          const watchliveUrl = this.watchLiveApi + station.plstation$callSign + '/?schema=1.0.0';
          return this.http.get(watchliveUrl).map(data => {
            const body = data.json();
            station.currentListing = body.currentListing;
            station.nextListing = body.nextListing;
          });
        }
      });
      // Wait for all requests to complete.
      Rx.Observable.forkJoin(...responses).subscribe(() => {
            project.next(stations);
            project.complete()
      });

    }, (error) => {
      this.mapErrorService.mapError(error, 'Listing service (1)');
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is you have a `forEach` loop firing off multiple requests, and you are calling `project.complete()` when the first of the http requests completes. You have to gather all of the requests together and only complete `project` when they have all responded. You could use `Rx.Observable.forkJoin()` for this.

Comment: Where have i to put this function exactly?

Comment: I put in how I think it might go, but I'm not really certain here. The important thing is you have to wait for all the requests to complete which you do by calling forkJoin with the array of observables.